# How to fix the device names of USB storage devices?

Tags: 12.04, usb-drive, raid

I would like to try building RAID system using two or more USB drives for just an experiment. But, the device names of USB drives will be changed whenever they reput or the system reboot.

For example: **/dev/sdb** changes to **/dev/sdc** etc.

Is there any good solution to fix the device names of USB drives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: use the UUID instead. Assuming you use `mdadm`, the `--examine` switch will tell you the UUIDs (or `sudo blkid`).

The UUID does not change, no matter what the device name is.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `mdadm`. I will try to use UUID. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming an USB drive is quite simple.

First go to Computer. Then, right click on your USB device and choose Rename. Give your desired name and Press Enter.

Comment: This problem is not about volume label name.
They are "device names" such as /dev/sdb or /dev/sdc or /dev/sdd and so on.